# Spread text across the entire line and custom line-to-line spacing

Tags: line

How can I get a line of **text** spread across the entire line width? As shown; with letter spacing increased (not only word spacing).

from:

[image]

to:

[image]

Lastly, how could I set a line-to-line spacing that would most approximate to that shown in the previous illustrations?

PS. Here's the code for the first image output:

```
% methamatics
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\emergencystretch 3em
% -------------------
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\hbadness=1000
% -------------------
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12}{7}\selectfont}
\setmathfont[]{STIX Two Math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures = {Historic}, Contextuals = Alternate, Kerning = On]{Hoefler Text Pro}

% \setmathrm
% [
%   Style = Historic,
%   Ligatures = Historic,
% ]
% {Hoefler Text Pro}

% \setmathsf
% [
%   Style = Historic,
%   Ligatures = Historic,
% ]
% {Hoefler Text Pro}

% \setboldmathrm
% [
%   Style = Historic,
%   Ligatures = Historic,
% ]
% {Hoefler Text Pro Bold}

%-CMDS
\newcommand{\tib}[1]{{\fontspec
    [
        Contextuals = LineFinal,
        Kerning = On,
    ]
    {Hoefler Text Pro Engraved One}
    \fontsize{24}{12}
    \selectfont #1 \normalfont \normalsize}}

\newcommand{\tisc}[1]{{\fontspec
    [
        Letters = SmallCaps,
        Kerning = On,
    ]
    {Hoefler Text Pro}
    \fontsize{20}{12}
    \selectfont #1 \normalfont \normalsize}}

%-DCMNT
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \tib{VECTOR ANALYSIS}\\[\baselineskip]
        \tisc{an introduction\\
        to \\
        vector methods} \\ 
        $$  $$
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the line to line spacing you can achieve it by

```
\vspace{length}
```

or

```
\vfill
```

in between sentences.

As for letter-to-letter spacing. LuaTeX with Microtype allows for the desired effect. With:

```
\textls[150]{VECTOR ANALYSIS}
```

However on XeTeX you need to use Fontspec and adjust the font features:

```
LetterSpace = ...

WordSpace = ...
```

[image]

I suggest doing so by creating a command to be able to share these features across different other fonts that you might use, e.g

*Say you're  sharing certain features for several titling styles, then by creating a command such as:*

```
\newcommand{\titlingFontFeatures}{%

    ...
    LetterSpace = 100,
    WordSpace = 2,
    ...
}
```

*you can then use:*

```
\newcommand{\bigTitle}[1]{{\fontspec
[
    \titlingFontFeatures
]
{Helvetica}
\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont#1
\par}}
```

*to share features to this new font.*

Microtype is just not an option if you're not using pdfLatex, and since you're this serious about fonts you might've migrated to something like XeTeX or LuaTeX a while ago, now, even on LuaTeX, Microtype doesn't have many features that actually work on it. Therefore Fontspec is the way to go.